# Weird Tokenization Error

Tags: python, twitter, tokenize

I'm trying to Tokenize tweets, but am running into a problem with looping through them.
For example, this works fine:

```
tweet = """This is an example Tweet!"""

# tokenize the sentence

print text
print list(token[1] for token in tokenize.generate_tokens(cStringIO.StringIO(text).readline)if token[1])
```

But, this does not:

```
for tweet in tweets: 
    text = tweet['tweet']

    # tokenize the sentence

    print text
    print list(token[1] for token in tokenize.generate_tokens(cStringIO.StringIO(text).readline)if token[1])
```

I get this list back:

```
Sickipedia is hilarious xD
['S', '\x00', 'i', '\x00', 'c', '\x00', 'k', '\x00', 'i', '\x00', 'p', '\x00', 'e', '\x00', 'd', '\x00', 'i', '\x00', 'a', '\x00', ' ', '\x00', 'i', '\x00', 's', '\x00', ' ', '\x00', 'h', '\x00', 'i', '\x00', 'l', '\x00', 'a', '\x00', 'r', '\x00', 'i', '\x00', 'o', '\x00', 'u', '\x00', 's', '\x00', ' ', '\x00', 'x', '\x00', 'D', '\x00']
```

When it should read something like:

```
Sikipedia is hilarious xD
['Sikipedia', 'is', 'hilarious', 'xD']
```

Any ideas? I'm using Python by the way w/ Mongo. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I missing something or could you just re.split(r'\s+', text)?

Comment: I could, but the tokenization module is much better at tokenizing punctuation than doing it manually with split. Was just curious if I could get it to execute faster. Will most likely use re.split() however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output suggests your text is encoded in UTF-16. Try printing the `repr()` of the text (which is a good idea in any case) and you should see the same `'\x00'`s between each character that you see in the tokenized output. You should see which form of UTF-16 it is (if it doesn't start with `\xff\xfe` or `\xfe\xff`) and then decode it, using the `decode` string method. You won't be able to feed unicode to `cStringIO`, so you'd have to write another function to replace `cStringIO.StringIO(text).readline`, or encode it back into a bytestring in a more appropriate encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The [tokenize Package](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tokenize-module.html/) in [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) is a good place to start. To handle some of the unique phenomena/strings found in twitter data, you can customize this package to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to tokenize tweets? As it says in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html), "The `tokenize` module provides a lexical scanner for Python source code". It doesn't seem likely that many tweets consist of Python source code.

If you're just trying to split the text into words, you should be using something like [re.split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split).

But anyway, the reason for the strange results is that your tweet is encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: I'm aware, but the Tokenize module can be used for other purposes too. Thanks, I'll try and fix that :)